# How to use on touch listener and on drag listener separately for horizontal scroll view in android?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a horizontal scroll view where I do an animation of scrolling to end and returning back to start of horizontal scroll view on onTouchListener,but I don't want to do this animation when the user scrolls manually to end.

```
hv_scroll_radio.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ObjectAnimator animator=ObjectAnimator.ofInt(hv_scroll_radio, "scrollX",100);
            animator.setDuration(300);
            animator.start();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ObjectAnimator animator=ObjectAnimator.ofInt(hv_scroll_radio, "scrollX",0);
                    animator.setDuration(300);
                    animator.start();
                }
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

need help thanks in advance.